# PHPからMSSQLのエージェントのジョブを起動したい

Tags: php, sql-server

標題の件ですが、PHPでどういった記述・手順をふめば良いのかインターネットで模索しているのですが、解決方法を見つけることができず困っています。

どなたかご存知の方はおりませんでしょうか？

当該のサイトはMSから取得したPDOのドライバを活用し、既にMSSQLをDataBaseとした動作を達成済みです（読み書き）。
IIS・ASP.NETじゃないとできない...とか仰られると困ってしまうのですが

（Apache2.4・PHP7.0が当方の環境）

====20180322追記====
頂きましたご見解から、現況行っている手続きは以下のとおりです。エラーが生じていてそのエラー内容はnago3さんのコメント下部に追加させて頂きました。

```
$db_j = new ms0connect_msdb();
$conn_j = $db_j->dbconnect();
try {
    $err_stage = "sql5";
    $sql5 = "sp_start_job :jobtitle";

    $param1 = "XXXXXX";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql5);
    $stmt->bindParam(":jobtitle", $param1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    switch ($err_stage){
        case "sql":
            error_log("### SQL Serverデータ取得失敗 ⇒".$sql5."###".$e->getMessage(),0);
            break;
        default:
            error_log("### SQL Serverデータ取得失敗 ⇒###".$e->getMessage(),0);
    }
} 
$conn_j = null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sp_start_jobを使えばできるのではないでしょうか。

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql

FreeTDSならtsqlコマンドが入りますのでシェル実行ができますが、MS純正のドライバでは未確認です。

https://serverfault.com/questions/776087/freetds-start-job-at-step-from-linux-python-script-on-mssql-db

Comment: この度は貴重なご見解をありがとうございます。お返事が遅れ申し訳ありませんでした。
ちょっと自分の力量からして、この記事に紹介された内容だけで達成できるのか不安があるのですが
トライアルしてみます。うまくいくと本当にいいのですが．．

Comment: 一先ずMS SQLServrのManagementStudioで　クエリ発行（新しいクエリとして開く画面）として
sp_start_job XXXXXXXを　実行してみたところ無事動作を確認しました。
PHPでも、普通にSELECT句のように記述されば良いのかな？という解釈で、本文のような手続きを行いました。
しかし下記エラーを招いてしまっています。接続のDataBaseはMSDBです。
本文に追記した部分と、以下エラー内容をご確認頂けますと幸いです、よろしくお願い致します。

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: trying to execute an empty query
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]ストアド プロシージャ 'sp_start_job' が見つかりませんでした。

Comment: 'sp_start_job' ではなく 'msdb.dbo.sp_start_job' としてみたら、どうなるでしょうか。

Comment: naga3さん、algさん、ご報告です、また引き続きお聞きしたいこともござまして
お手すきであればご見解をよろしくお願い致します。

一応にストアド経由のジョブ実行、無事達成されるようになりました。
①初歩的なコーディングミス：
$stmt = $conn_j->prepare($sql5);としなければならないところを、
誤って$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql5);としていた点を修正。
②ジョブ名をパラメータのバインド方式でなく直に書く形態へ変更、
$sql5 = "exec sp_start_job XXXXXXX";


１点残念なのが、ジョブ起動が達成されているのにも関わらず
Excptionでキャッチされている点です。
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: trying to execute an empty query
とかいうメッセージが出ています。
キャッチしないようにすれば良い、といえばそれまでですが、
errorと表示されている事象を見過ごして良いものか、どういう理由でerror
に分類されているのか悩んでいます。　しっかり認識した上で相応の対策を図りたく　無視すべきerrorなのか、どういう事象でerrorとなっているのか
ご存知でしたら教えてください。

Comment: ひょっとしたら、$sql5 = "exec sp_start_job ’XXXXXXX’";　ジョブ部分をシングルクォートでくくったらうまくいったかも。。。

Comment: @naga3  sp_start_jobを教えて頂かなければ、ストアド経由のジョブ実行が可能であることを認識しておりませんでした。
PHPでストアドをどう起動するのかで少々時間を費やしてしまいましたが、無事解決に至れました、ありがとうございます。
（PDOでストアド実行のためのクエリにはexecが必要、sp_start_jobで指定するジョブ名は''シングルクォートで括る）